# how to solve problems with persistence mapDB?

Tags: java, gwt, mapdb

i am doing my project with GWT and Madb. The problem is that MapDb every time it deletes the contents of the db. How can I do to keep the db persistent?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your configuration uses file store? If you have something like `DBMaker.newMemory...()`

Comment: yes i use DBMaker.fileDB(new File("db")).closeOnJvmShutdown().make();